# UI5 - OData (Response) Object Normalization

Tags: sapui5

I'm looking for a method in the library to convert an OData response object into a normalized js object that can be sent into another ODataModel.create function. An OData "object" would be an OData REST response containing 'd', the '__meta', the 'results', etc.

I have a working solution with custom methods in a Utilities module but I'm not too sure about its resilience to all possible OData rules.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to have the `d`, `__meta` and `results` section in a valid OData body:

1. The `d` potion is optional. You may also just form your body as a regular object such as:

   {
       Id: 12345,
       Name: 'This is a valid OData body'
   }
2. The `__metadata` section is optional as well and may be left out.
3. The `results` section is something you will receive when you query an Entity Set. If you query a single Entity (by providing its key), this section is left out as there will only be one result. You can't use the `results` section when you want to submit entities to the OData service, as every submission is supposed to happen in a separate operations.

With that, your normalisation/processing code could be very simple and look like:

```
jQuery.each(odata.results, function(idx, value) {
    var body = value.d ? value.d : value;
    delete body.__metadata;
    // Do something with the body, e.g.:
    ODataModel.create("/AwesomeEntity", body);
});
```

I hope this makes life easier? Full OData v2 JSON specs are available here:
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/

Comment: I have a function and it works - I'm looking for something inside the UI5 framework that does the same.

Comment: The `d` portion is NOT optional in **response** body. [OData V2 JSON](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/): "Security Note: In responses payloads (not request payloads) all the JSON representations described in this section are wrapped by an outer most object that includes a single name/value pair. The name of the name/value pair is always "d"."